# I am using springer nature \documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}, and I need citations like (Nielsen and Chuang 2010) but it is coming like [1]

Tags: citing, natbib, springernature

I am using springer nature

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl},
```

and I need citations like `(Baireuther 2018)` but it is coming like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WOtw.png). I have used `\usepackage{natbib}`. Followed by:

```
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

I dont know where I am getting wrong.
By sample tex file input:

```
@article{baireuther2018machine,
  title={Machine-learning-assisted correction of 
         correlated qubit errors in a topological code},
  author={Baireuther, P and others},
  journal={Quantum},
  volume={2},
  pages={48},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Verein zur F{\"o}rderung des Open Access 
             Publizierens in den Quantenwissenschaften}
}
```

sample:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\title{ aaa bbb ccc}
\author*[1]{\fnm{xxx} \sur{ yyy}}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
aaaaa \cite{baireuther2018machine}
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Coming as [image]

Comment: Maybe provide a complete but minimal example that can be compiled.

Comment: See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography

Comment: BTW, you are looking for a "author-year" citation style.

Comment: HI.. edited in question with minimizal example

Comment: yes author year , I want (Baireuther 2018) instead of [1]

Answer (score 2):

Using `\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}` already defines a bibliography style namely `\bibliographystyle{sn-mathphys}`. Therefore writing `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` tries to redefine the bibliography style and causes an error.
One possible solution is to just write `\documentclass{sn-jnl}` without "`sn-mathphys`" or you may edit the definitions in `sn-jnl.cls` itself.

Comment: Thanks. It worked!